# `getStaticProps` to populate page header/footer

Tags: reactjs, next.js, vercel

I am building a project in Next. Currently, I have a custom App component that mounts a Header and Footer component.

Now I want to populate the content of the header/footer from an API (at build time since it won't change very frequently). However, `getStaticProps` is only available for pages, not components.

How do I fetch the data at build time and pass it to the header/footer components?

Answer (score 2):

Assuming `App` is rendered on the index page inside `pages`, you just pass it down the drain.

**pages/index.js**

```js
import App from '../components/App'

const Index = ({data}) => {
  return(
    <div>
      <App data={data} />
    </div>
  )
}

export const getStaticProps = async () => {
  const res = await fetch('...')
  const data = await res.json()

  return { props: { data } } 
}
```

And then in your App component you access it using `props`.

**components/App.js**

```js
import Header from './Header'
import Footer from './Footer'

const App = (props) => { // I believe you can also use {data} directly instead of props
  return(
    <div>
      <Header data={props.data} />
      <Footer data={props.data} />
    </div>
  )
}
```

And then you do the same thing in your `Header` and `Footer` component.

**components/Header.js**

```js
const Header = ({data}) => {
  return(
    <div>
      {data}
    </div>
  )
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. However, I don't know if it would work. When I mean an app component I mean a custom app component (`_app.jsx`). That is where the header/footer are mounted as they are shared throughout all of the pages in the site. Thing is that I haven't found a way for that custom app component to fetch from an API at build time because `getStaticProps` doesn't seem to work on anything that isn't a page. i.e. my index page is mounted by the app not vice versa. Sorry if I wasn't clear in my question :(

Comment: Would it be ok to use react context here to avoid the props passing ?